# Using Parameterized Queries/Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

I'm new to php coding and have been told by others that I need to be using parameterized queries/prepared statements for my php scripts and MySQL database. I've looked at other examples of scripting these prepared statements and they usually refer to user login functions. My query is just a web form to capture user inputted data and store in database (SQL insert as opposed to SQL select). I am hoping someone can help me with how to script the php to prevent sql injections. Also hoping someone can let me know whether these prepared statements should also be used in php SQL Select scripts where I am only displaying database records on a form. Thanks in advance!

Here are the two php files I am using, the first is my database connection script:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'fakeuser');
DEFINE ("DB_PSWD", 'fakepassword');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'newspaper');

$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);

?>
```

Web form PHP script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php

$errors = "false";

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = $subErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = $sub = $newrecord = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["Name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      $errors = "true";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      $errors = "true";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["Website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["Comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }

if (empty($_POST["Subscription"])) {
    $subErr = "Subscription is required";
    $errors = "true";
    }
 else {
    $sub = test_input($_POST["Subscription"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Southern Tier Daily News</h2>
<form method="post" action="Newspaper3.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

<img src="https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/dnews.com/content/tncms/custom/image/5eec4204-483e-11e6-93c8-97ef236dc6c5.jpg?_dc=1468334339" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Newspaper Subscription Request</legend>  
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="Website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="Comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
  Subscription:
   <select name="Subscription">
       <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
   <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
   <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
   <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select> 
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $subErr;?></span>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Visit Admin Page</a>
 </fieldset>
</form>



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $errors == "false") 
    {
    include('connect-mysql.php');



$fname = $_POST['Name'];
$femail = $_POST['Email'];
$fcomment = $_POST['Comment'];
$fsubsciption = $_POST['Subscription'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (Name, Email, Comment, Subscription) VALUES ('$fname',
'$femail', '$fcomment', '$fsubsciption')";

      if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))  {
           die(mysqli_error($dbcon));  //and die('error inserting new record') ;       

  }     // end of nested if statement

  // else
        $newrecord = "1 record added to the database";

}  // end of main if statement

?>

<?php

echo $newrecord

?>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED CODE with Prepared Statement 9/3/17: See bottom of script (Please tell me if you see any issues with this) Also I've commented out the !mysqli_query IF statement below the prepared statement as I thought this was now redundent, but please tell me if it is still required.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php

$errors = "false";

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = $subErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = $sub = $newrecord = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["Name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      $errors = "true";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      $errors = "true";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["Website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["Comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }

if (empty($_POST["Subscription"])) {
    $subErr = "Subscription is required";
    $errors = "true";
    }
 else {
    $sub = test_input($_POST["Subscription"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Southern Tier Daily News</h2>
<form method="post" action="Newspaper3.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

<img src="https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/dnews.com/content/tncms/custom/image/5eec4204-483e-11e6-93c8-97ef236dc6c5.jpg?_dc=1468334339" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Newspaper Subscription Request</legend>  
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="Website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="Comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
  Subscription:
   <select name="Subscription">
       <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
   <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
   <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
   <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select> 
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $subErr;?></span>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Visit Admin Page</a>
 </fieldset>
</form>



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $errors == "false") 
    {
    include('connect-mysql.php');


$fname = $_POST['Name'];
$femail = $_POST['Email'];
$fcomment = $_POST['Comment'];
$fsubsciption = $_POST['Subscription'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (Name, Email, Comment, Subscription) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sqlinsert)) {
echo "SQL error"; }
else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss",$fname, $femail, $fcomment, $fsubsciption);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    echo '1 record added to the database';

      //if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))  {
           //die(mysqli_error($dbcon));        

  }     // end of nested IF statement

  // else
        //$newrecord = "1 record added to the database";

}  // end of main if statement

?>

<?php

echo $newrecord

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you always need prepared statements. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @jeroen I'm having trouble knowing how to script the prepared statements.